# Как заставить читать бота, читать беседу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Давным давно, делал бота, на модуле vk_api. Делал без каких-либо LongPoll, CallBack. Но в связи, изменение политики VK, пришлось делать на нём. 
Начал с простого, решил попробовать сделать группу, как бота. Написал код. Код - работает. Когда пишу боту, всё отвечает. Именно в ЛС сообщества. Но решил сделать для беседы. Добавил бота, предоставил всё что нужно. Но.. Почему то не работает.

Подскажите, что не так.

***Код:***

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from samp_client.client import SampClient

token = 'd25778e160a0beaac30bdbae********************************************b58ac0bf7'
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)

def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message})

with SampClient(address='185.169.134.68', port=7777, rcon_password='password') as client:
    info = client.get_server_info()


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.from_chat:
            request = event.text
            if request == "!evolve02":
                write_msg(event.chat_id, 'Информация о сервере: Evolve 02: ' + '\n\nНазвание: ' + str(info.hostname) + '\nИгроки: ' + str(info.players))
            if request == "тест":
                write_msg(event.chat_id, '+')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это из-за `VkLongPoll`. В [документации](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/longpoll.html) указано, что это модуль для пользователей. Так как Вы авторизуетесь с ключом сообщества, Вам требуется `VkBotLongPoll`. Обратите внимание, что он в другом модуле, а именно в `vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotLongPoll`

Вот пример рабочего бота:

```py
from random import random
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


vk_session = VkApi(token="[Ваш токен]")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "[id сообщества]")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9)
        chat_id = int(event.chat_id)
        message = "[Ваш ответ]"

        vk.messages.send(
            random_id=random_id,
            chat_id=chat_id,
            message=message,
        )
```

**UPD:**
Не забывайте про права. Если не упомянуть бота, то он просто не увидит Ваши сообщения. Ещё можно дать доступ ко всей переписке или сделать его администратором.

**UPD 2:**
Вот готовый бот специально для Вас <3 (вставьте токен, id сообщества и rcon_password):

```py
from random import random
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from samp_client.client import SampClient


with SampClient(address='185.169.134.68', port=7777, rcon_password='[Ваш пароль]') as client:
    info = client.get_server_info()

vk_session = VkApi(token='[Ваш токен]')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "[id сообщества]")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

def write_msg(chat_id, message):
    random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9)

    vk.messages.send(
            random_id=random_id,
            chat_id=chat_id,
            message=message,
        )

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:

        request = event.object.get('text')
        chat_id = event.chat_id

        if request == "!evolve02":
            write_msg(chat_id, 'Информация о сервере: Evolve 02: ' + '\n\nНазвание: ' + str(info.hostname) + '\nИгроки: ' + str(info.players))
        if request == "тест":
            write_msg(chat_id, '+')
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Не работает. Если, я пишу ему в беседе, то ничего не происходит, даже в консоле. Но, как сразу я ему пишу в ЛС, то пишет ошибку:
:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Полная ошибка - https://pastebin.com/9UmqS8SP

Comment: @stepanboi Приведите, пожалуйста, код, из-за которого возникает эта ошибка. Я постараюсь Вам помочь. Мой пример точно работает, я его не раз проверял.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3qu61ExR

Comment: @stepanboi Я обновил ответ, попробуйте то, что я написал. И да, удалите комментарий со ссылкой на Ваш код. Желательно, смените токен и rcon_password.

Comment: Видимо я делаю, что-то не так. rcon_password, за него не беспокойтесь, это так надо. 

Вот ошибка - https://pastebin.com/sUwh0HwE
Кажется, надо что-то в группе включить. Или нет?

Comment: @stepanboi Вам неразрешён доступ. Перейдите в `Управление группой -> Работа с API -> Ключи доступа`. Убедитесь, что у вашего ключа есть права на сообщения сообщества, также проверьте его правильность.

Comment: @stepanboi По тому же пути на вкладке `Long Poll API` убедитесь, что оно включено.

Comment: Права доступа: управление сообществом, сообщения сообщества, фотографии, документы, стена
Создан С. Зелениным, сегодня в 19:18

LongPoll - включен.

Comment: @stepanboi Вкладка `Long Poll API -> Типы событий`, включены входящие и исходящие сообщения? Это, наверное, последнее, чем могу помочь.

Comment: хахахах, я дурачок. Всё работает. Просто нета группа была указана в longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "ТУТ")

Comment: спасибо тебе большое!

Comment: @stepanboi Я даже немного волновался за Вас. Очень рад, что у Вас всё получилось! Пометьте тогда ответ как правильный, это будет лучшая благодарность для меня <3